# PHP while loop to make a table of images

Tags: php, mysql, image, while-loop, html-table

I am attempting to create a PHP script that will build a table of images from a database. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to properly nest my while loops to make a 6x(how ever many are in the db) table. I understand the concept but I am new to PHP and just can't wrap my head around doing it here.

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("images");

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1");
echo "<table>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?>

<img src="<?php echo $row["images1"]; ?>" height="150" width="150">

<?php echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Note that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)); don't use them in new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you keep a count of how many images you have processed you can use `if($count % 6 == 0)` to test if you are at the 6th item in the list. So your loop would look like the following:

```
$c = 0; //our count
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
  if(($count % 6) == 0){  // will return true when count is divisible by 6
    echo "<tr>";
  }
  echo "<td>";
  ?>
  <img src="<?php echo $row["images1"]; ?>" height="150" width="150">
  <?php
  echo "</td>";
  $c++;   // Note we are incrementing the count before the check to close the row
  if(($count % 6) == 0){
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
```